# Getting an error with rendering macros after upgrading to Confluence 4.2

Tags: jira, confluence, wiki-markup

After I update Confluence from 3.5 to 4.2.3, I have the following error:

```
Error rendering macro 'list-data' : Unsupported type: class
org.randombits.confluence.metadata.reference.WikiReference
```

[image]

So it looks like that problem with rendering of macro, in this field I have list-data which I can't edit. In some other fields (not only in list-data) such as text-data  have the same problem.

I found a workaround to this problem, but it only helps in local cases, not for  the whole space.

I posted the same question on Atlassian Q&A site. 
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/64871/error-rendering-macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by updating data and with adding escaping characters to this text.